# Swapping list values using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to swap the list as explained below. I want to retain the count of list with some element values(not all) to be swapped from 'primary' to 'secondary'.

```
namespace listswap
{

    public class emp
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string primary { get; set; }
        public string fName { get; set; }
        public string lName { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var empList = new List<emp>();
         empList.AddRange(new emp[] { new emp {primary = "Yes", id = 1, fName = "Vivek", lName = "Ranjan", state = "TN", country = "India"},
                                     new emp { primary = "No", id = 2, fName = "Deepak", lName = "Kumar", state = "AP", country = "UK"},

        });


            /* Desired list :    
            No of list 1 with two elements              
            empList[0]. primary = "Yes", id = 1, fName = "Vivek", lName = "Ranjan", state = "TN", country = "India"
            empList[1]. primary = "No", id = 2, fName = "Vivek", lName = "Ranjan", state = "TN", country = "India"

            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is basics and as simple as:

```
var l1 = empList.Where(c=>c.primary == "Yes").ToList();
var l2 = empList.Where(c=>c.primary == "No").ToList();
```

For list of lists:

```
var result = empList.GroupBy(c => c.primary).Select(c => c.ToList()).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

```
var primary = empList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.primary == "Yes");

var r = empList.Select(c => new emp
{
    primary = c.primary,
    id = c.id,
    fName = primary != null ? primary.fName : c.fName,
    lName = primary != null ? primary.lName : c.lName,
    state = primary != null ? primary.state : c.state,
    country = primary != null ? primary.country : c.country
}).ToList();
```

Comment: There should be one list empList with two element

Comment: @GirishKumar, if you mean `one list empList with two lists` then see changes. Other way the question makes no sense to me because you already have one list with 2 elements...

Comment: My desire list  is
element 0. primary = "Yes", id = 1, fName = "Vivek", lName = "Ranjan", state = "TN", country = "India"
            element 1. primary = "No", id = 2, fName = "Vivek", lName = "Ranjan", state = "TN", country = "India"

Comment: Your result is not as I am excpecting

Comment: @GirishKumar, I can not get you - you already have the desired result in empList list... Can you elaborate?

Comment: As I pasted my desire result in above comment, empList[1] has value of empList[0] except primary = "No" & id = 2

Comment: @GirishKumar, you say `My desire list is element 0. primary = "Yes", id = 1, fName = "Vivek", lName = "Ranjan", state = "TN", country = "India" element 1. primary = "No", id = 2`, but the list empList is exactly what you are looking for man.

Comment: What abt empList [1] state, country values? It takes from empList [0]

Comment: Where the value swapping in your answer

Comment: @GirishKumar, oh I see now. You should always describe what you want. See changes.

Comment: Can you do some optimization to avoid assigning the values. Let's say I have 20 properties, then it wouldn't be like LINQ. I mean avoid wring fName = primary != null ? primary.fName : c.fName,
    lName = primary != null ? primary.lName : c.lName,
    state = primary != null ? primary.state : c.state,
    country = primary != null ? primary.country : c.country

Comment: This looks similar to for loop, could you optimize

Comment: @GirishKumar, you will have to create a new object and assign values. other way is to do a deep clone of [0] element and assign only id and primary fields.